# How to replace a color with another using GraphicsMagick Nodejs

Tags: node.js, background-color, graphicsmagick

I have an image with black background. I want to change it to have white background. Is that possible to achieve using GraphicsMagick in Nodejs?

I tried `gm("test.png").fill("white")` but this didn't work for me.
I did some search and found there is a convert command but not sure there is equivalent function for it. `gm.convert` ends up giving error.

Comment: Please show the image, or something **very similar** in terms of content and filetype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one step in your *GraphicsMagick* command, you do not specify which color you want to replace. You need to add [opaque](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#opaque) option to select the background color of your image:

```
gm('test.png')
  .fill('white')
  .opaque("black")
  .write('out.png', function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Note there are probably other ways to do it.

ImageMagick doc: [Replace a Specific Color](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace)

Answer (score 1):

Find below link having all options for graphicsmagics

[link][1]

```
gm("img.png").highlightColor(color)
```

Comment: I get following error with this when writing the file after adding highlightColor - Error: Command failed: convert: unrecognized option `-highlight-color' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1827. This is the code I use gm('test.png').highlightColor('white').write('convert.png', function(err) {});