# Randomly color various parts of an image

Tags: html

I'm working on a personal project and I'm trying to figure out how to randomly 'color' various parts of an image. The result I'm looking for is like the following image generator when you click "Generate":

[Random Color Image Generator](https://jwebgen.com/generate)

I'm not even sure where to begin. Is it possible to assign different Element IDs to a single image?

Thank you!
Laura

Comment: The site you mentioned is sending the properties to the server and then retrieving the image from the server.

Comment: "Is it possible to assign different Element IDs to a single image" no, as it is a single element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure HTML project from what I understand of your requirements. HTML is not a programming language, it is a markup language for displaying things. Where anything apart from display is involved, a scripting or programming language is needed.

In your project, HTML would be used for the front-end, for example to gather information for example about which color goes where, and to show a 'generate' button that the viewer can click.

You will then need (to build) an actual program in the back-end (on a server etc) that will generate the image based on the parameters collected from the viewer.

The HTML front-end can then fetch the generated image and display it to the viewer.

The back-end can be built in a number of ways in a number of programming languages. PHP is a typical language for something like this. It can also be done in javascript (node.js), python, etc.

A good starting point is looking at open-source projects on github. A quick search showed me a few projects which might be in line with yours.

- https://github.com/kotekipiesek/3D-Pony-Creator
- https://github.com/lat9nq/make-pony
- https://github.com/Tailszefox/Pony-Fusion

Even with the programming language, you would typically not interact deeply with the JPG or PNG file formats. Your scripting language would use a library to do this. ImageMagick is one such popular library.

Here is a question that I think you might ask if you pick node.js as your language:
[How to replace a color with another using GraphicsMagick Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663953/how-to-replace-a-color-with-another-using-graphicsmagick-nodejs)

Comment: Thank you Pranab!

I wasn't sure which language this would require so I put HTML. I will certainly check out the resources you listed.

I appreciate your help! :)